Possible reputation abuse
I was looking for an answer that involved CallWindowProc and I stumbled upon this question
Looks like this user has posted the question already knowing the answer, answered it right away (by the look on the timestamps) as a "different person", and got upvotes for it.
Maybe it was supposed to be a Community Wiki question. I don't know, just found it weird

It looks as answered by the same person.

The question was answered by the same user and it's perfectly fine since our goal is to share knowledge and make the internet better, so further users can benefit from it.
See: Help Center > Answering on Can I answer my own question?

Not only it is ok, but also encouraged! Thanks
